# Wireshark can't decrypt TLS from a specific python library

Tags: python, ssl, encryption, wireshark

I have a problem. I'm using Wireshark 4.0.8. I created my ssl file to store my "(pre)-master-secrets". I can thus decrypt TLS from my browser or from different python libraries without problem. But I cannot decrypt the TLS when my requests are made with the TLS-CLIENT python library (https://github.com/FlorianREGAZ/Python-Tls-Client) which allows the use of HTTP/2 and TLS fingerprints of real browsers.

However, I manage to decrypt the requests made with Curl-CFFI ("curl-impersonate" but for python) (https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi) which also copies the HTTP and TLS fingerprints of real browsers. Does anyone have an idea why I can't decrypt TLS when I use the "TLS-Client" python library? (I'm not sure, but it seems that pre master secrets are not written to my ssl file when using this specific library) despite port number 443 on the server is used for the encrypted TLS.

Comment: Support for writing the key file needs to be implement in the TLS library used. In tls-client you use it is not implement, hence you cannot use it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for your quick reply.  Do you have any idea how I could decrypt the TLS made by this library (originally written in Go, the python one is a binder I suppose)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks. At least I know now that the problem is not from my operating system or from Wireshark but from this specific library that simply can't write in my SSLKEYLOGFILE

Comment: @big-bg If the python library doesn't support SSLKEYLOGFILE then you can try running the TLS traffic through a TLS proxy. There are TLS proxies that can output the decrypted traffic in PCAP format, which is handy if you want to analyze the decrypted HTTP/2 traffic in Wireshark.